# I am able to register the values to server from android but not able to get JSon response

Tags: android, json

I am able to register the values to server from android but not able to get JSon response.
Heres my code ,it was supposed to show output in userareaActivity :

my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="twin.com.heyjson.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="password" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_marginTop="40sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Register"
            android:onClick="hit"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

main activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.net.ResponseCache;


import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText emailview, numberview, pwview;
    Button registerview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        emailview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        numberview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        pwview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
        registerview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    }

    public void hit(View v) {
        String email = emailview.getText().toString();
        String contact = numberview.getText().toString();
        String pw = pwview.getText().toString();
        JSONObject a = new JSONObject();

        try {
            a.put("mail", email);
            a.put("num", contact);
            a.put("pass", pw);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (a.length() > 0) {
            new SendJsonDataToServer().execute(String.valueOf(a));
        }
    }

    class  SendJsonDataToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String JsonResponse = null;
            String JsonDATA = params[0];
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("example.com");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                // is output buffer writter
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
//set headers and method
                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(JsonDATA);
// json data
                writer.close();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
//input stream
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                JsonResponse = buffer.toString();
//response data
                Log.i("o/p:", JsonResponse);
                try {
//send to post execute
                    return JsonResponse;
                } catch (Exception e){

                }
                return null;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("wtf", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.i("Here it is:",s);
        Log.e("Here it is:",s);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(s);
            int status= jsonResponse.getInt("status");
            String message =jsonResponse.getString("message");

            JSONArray arr = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data");

                if ( status==1){
                    for (int i=0;i<arr.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject lol = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                        String token = lol.getString("token");
                        String email = lol.getString("email");


                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("message", message);
                        intent.putExtra("token", token);
                        intent.putExtra("email", email);

                        startActivity(intent);


                    }}


            else {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Registration failed").setNegativeButton("retry",null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }




        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }}
}
```

Activity_user_area.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="twin.com.heyjson.UserAreaActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Message" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="token" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="email" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


UserAreaActivity :



import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class UserAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);
        final TextView tar =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        final TextView zar =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        final TextView par =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);



        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String message=intent.getStringExtra("message");
        String token =intent.getStringExtra("token");
        String email=intent.getStringExtra("email");



        tar.setText(message);
        zar.setText(token);
        par.setText(email);



    }
}
```

my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UserAreaActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before blindly reading the input stream, try to check the response status with,

```
int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode()
```

If the code is any of 200 series, then you have successfully posted the data to server. Based on the code value, read data from either from `urlConnection.getInputStream()` or `urlConnection.getErrorStream()`

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using to post data is right but you are creating an HttpUrlConnection with POST properties and this connection is intended to POST your data to some specific web service endpoint, which accept data as POST parameters. So how can you use same HttpUrlConnection to get data from server. In that case you need to create a different HttpUrlConnection with different URL that is intended to get data from server. Ideally you shouldn't use same AsyncTask to POST and GET data from web server use different for both POST and GET.

Comment: can you elaborate little more plz?like from the first asynctask i should call second asynctask from the onpostexceute method ? is that so ?but my server automatically reponds when registration is completed.So what will i declare as Url in the new asyntasks url ?again the same url? i dont think in that way new connection has to be created. Because maybe it will take it as a new request again , and when new request is sent without the form entries,server wont respond.So looking at my code can u tell me again whats wrong and why m not able to get response and display it?Thx for ur efforts bro :)