# picasso is not able to load image in android

Tags: android, picasso, universal-image-loader, android-glide

i am using android api level 17 as minimum and have included internet permissions in manifest file.
But i am not able to get image. I want to fetch images from my server , the link i am using is proper. check my code :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView im;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("example.com").into(im);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Context` to your `Activity` instead:

```
 Picasso.with(this).load("example.com").into(im);
```

Comment: if possible can i get your email ?

Comment: Can you try to answer this one also if possible please [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682228/i-am-able-to-register-the-values-to-server-from-android-but-not-able-to-get-json)

Comment: As I said, you have to accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: i did the same day , i dont know what  happened that day maybe error. Now its done.